# Unable to set capability CAP_SETFCAP by user

Tags: linux, security, capabilities

The question is about capabilities.
I need to allow user to set capabilities using setcap.
When I call it by root all goes fine, eg `$ sudo setcap cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search+ep ./bin_file`

```
$ getcap ./bin_file
./bin_file = cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search+ep
```

but when i run the command with user privileges...

```
$ /sbin/setcap cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search+ep ./bin_file
unable to set CAP_SETFCAP effective capability: Operation not permitted
```

I added the following string into `/etc/security/capability.conf`:

```
cap_setfcap,cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search user
```

but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

If a user/process has `cap_setfcap` or `cap_dac_override`, then it is trivial to gain root access.

If the user is trusted you can add them to group sudo/sudoers (depends on configuration), and they can use `sudo`.

You can even add rules to `/etc/sudoers.d/` to allow the user to run `setcap` only, and only in the specified ways. However this will just give you a false sense of security.

Answer (score 1):

Because your `/sbin/setcap` doesn't have `CAP_SETFCAP` bit in neither inheritable set, nor permitted set. The file's effective bit is not set as well.

And as `richard` said, it 'll make no sense of security if you grant these 2 capabilities to any non-root user